# How to translate text/HTML that has stylistic line breaks?

Tags: html, internationalization, gettext

The general question here is how do you mark text up for translation on an HTML page when the position of the line breaks have to look eye pleasing (as opposed to the line break aways happening after a specific word)?

I have a web page I want to translate into 5 different languages. In some places, I have text like "Enjoyed by 10,000 happy users" under a small icon that needs to be displayed in an eye pleasing way. This looks good as the noun phrase is on its own line and each line has about the same number of letters:

```
         <icon>

       Enjoyed by
   10,000 happy users
```

Do I send this text to be translated as this?

```
Enjoyed by <br> 10,000 happy users
```

Problems:

1. By adding markup to the text it makes it unlikely I can reuse the string elsewhere but I can't see any other options.
2. How do I cope with how I place the 
    in the translated text given the translated text will have a different number of letters (e.g. "Genossen von 
    10.000 glückliche Benutzer" in German)? Just review how each one renders on the page manually and adjust the 
    myself after the translations come back?

I can't see any clean way to do this. I could remove the markup and try to write some server code that will add the break in a nice place but I can't see how it's possible to automate (e.g. putting noun phrases on their own line if possible when the previous line has enough letters). CSS has even less options to do this.

Comment: What does the current markup for "Enjoyed by 10,000 happy users" look like?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Oops, see the edit. It has a <br> character in the text.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat subjective, but I think your choices are to either trust your translators to format the HTML, or trust them to come up with copy that fits your design. Trying to engineer your way to a "clean" solution with server code sounds like it will achieve the exact opposite.

Make sure your design is good enough to cope with a *reasonable* range of word lengths. If your layout lives and dies by the text being exactly X characters long, then it isn't well designed. You can always ask your translators to try and write a translation in less than a maximum number of characters. This is why we still have human translators - they are also copywriters :)

Comment: I think you're missing the part about keeping certain words together, it's not just about line length. What would you do for this example then? Just have no <br>s anywhere and allow "10,000 happy" to be split between lines no matter what the language? Line breaks like these are in every well designed website, but I've never seen it addressed what you do for translations.

Comment: You can keep words together using non-breaking spaces. You can make line-endings render in HTML by using CSS whitespace attributes.

Comment: So what would you do for this example then? Would the English text sent for translation have non-breaking spaces in it with instructions to the translators to put non-breaking spaces in the same place (note that the language might change the word order or even the number of words)? Or would you just put no special characters in the English text and do the fix some other way?

Comment: What would I do? I would send plain text and make sure my design could flow it. If that was impossible I'd ask the translators to add markup in the appropriate place.  You said certain words must remain together, so I suggested nbsp, but equally could be <span> tags or whatever.